# Is the arguments list to a for loop evaluated once in bash?

Tags: bash

When writing

```
for a in `ls`
do
...
done
```

Is the ls command run only once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's evaluated only once.

But you [should never iterate over `ls` output with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Also, [`$(...)` is preferred over `` `...` ``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: And [a `for` loop is the wrong tool for line-by-line iteration in the first place](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: But doing something with each file is okay with `for f in *`, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I never thought about these pitfalls even though I knew word splitting occurs after backquotes evaluation and * expansion.